# How to use the eigen decomposition in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, algebra

In the follow algorithm weights is a 2017x2017 symmetric matrix of rank 7.

I'm trying to do something with the columns of the eigendecomposition however I can't even get them to sum back to the original matrix. neoweights1 = weights, but neoweights = something totally different. What's the error here?

```
w,v = np.linalg.eig(weights)

neoweights1 = w2 * (v2 @ v2.T)
neoweights = np.zeros((matsize,matsize))
for i in range(7):
    neoweights += np.real(w2[i] * (v2[i] @ v2[i].T))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't show where w2 and v2 are coming from but I guess they are also the the result of np.linalg.eig. In that case note that each column in v2 is an eigen vector. But `v2[i]` gives you a row.

Following that, `v2[i] @ v2[i].T` is a vector dot product, meaning the whole expression `neoweights += np.real(w2[i] * (v2[i] @ v2[i].T))` just adds a scalar value to every element of the matrix.

This is what you want instead:

```py
neoweights = sum(np.real(np.outer(w[i] * v[:,i], v[:,i])) for i in range(7))
```

And for the matrix expression, you have to be careful when and how you do the multiplication with the weights. This should work:
`np.real(w * v @ v.T)`